# How to return a list of names in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am writing a simple program that deals with rainfall for places in the UK. Each place has a name, location in degrees north and east, and list of rainfall figures.

How do I return a list of the names of all places, example: 
[London, Cardiff, St Helier].

Error:
1. Couldn't match type
2. list comprehension

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List

type Place = (String, Int, Int, [Int])

testData :: [Place]
testData = [("London", 51.5, -0.1, [0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0]),
            ("Cardiff", 51.5, -3.2, [12, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0, 2]),
            ("St Helier", 49.2, -2.1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 10, 0])]

listNames :: Place -> [String]
listNames details = [name | (name,north,east,[figure]) <- details]
```

Comment: Look at the type you say `listNames` has. Can `details` be a `Place`?

Comment: You also have an syntax error `listNames = ...` it should be `listNames :: ...`

Comment: changed it to ``` list names :: ...

Comment: You want to take list of places, and then you can just do
`listNames = map fst`

Comment: Can 51.5 be an Int ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your current solution:

`type Place = (String, Int, Int, [Int])` but `("London", 51.5, -0.1, [0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0])` The problem here is that you have specified the two middle fields of the tuple to be `Int`s, but you pass in `51.5` and `-0.1`, which are fractional values. I would recommend changing `Place` to: `type Place = (String, Float, Float, [Int])` (you could also look into using a record).

Your `listNames` function's signature epxects only a single place: `listNames :: Place -> [String]`, but you actually mean to have it take a list of places. You should change it to `listNames :: [Place] -> [String]`.

Your list comprehension uses a restrictive pattern match, while you want one that accepts pretty much anything: the `[figure]` part of the pattern match only matches a list with a single element, which you are binding to `figure`. Make sure that you understand the difference between the list type notation `[a]` and the list constructor `[1, 2, 3]`.

Not only that, but you can disregard all but the place name anyway: `[name | (name, _, _, _) <- details]`.

All together, your code would become:

```
type Place = (String, Float, Float, [Int])

testData :: [Place]
testData = [("London", 51.5, -0.1, [0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0]),
            ("Cardiff", 51.5, -3.2, [12, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0, 2]),
            ("St Helier", 49.2, -2.1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 10, 0])]

listNames :: [Place] -> [String]
listNames details = [name | (name, _, _, _) <- details]
```

Comment: `fst` only works on pairs, not quadruples. There are libraries that offer class-polymorphic alternatives; if you want to avoid imports, I've also seen the convention of defining `frst` for triples and `first` for quadruples. But a real record is even better still.