# Write a function that returns a list of names in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have test data for Students and the marks they have attained.
How do i write a function called nameList, that will make a list of just the names of students?

```
import Data.Char

type StudentMark = (String, Int)

testData :: [StudentMark]
testData = [("John", 53), ("Sam", 16), ("Kate", 85), ("Jill", 65),
            ("Bill", 37), ("Amy", 22), ("Jack", 41), ("Sue", 71)]

nameList :: [StudentMark] -> [String]
nameList = [name | (name, _) <- name]
```

Example: ["John", "Sam", "Kate", "Jill", "Bill", "Amy", "Jack", "Sue"]

Comment: Hint: take a look at `map`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map

Comment: When faced with a problem you don't know how to solve, break it down into smaller pieces. How do you write a function of type `StudentMark -> String`, i.e. which gets the name of a single student? Once you have that, you can look at applying a single function over all the elements of a list.

Comment: I made an attempt but i cant solve my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return a list of names in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61323142/how-to-return-a-list-of-names-in-haskell)

Answer (score 0):

You were so close! Take a close look at your function:

```
nameList = [name | (name, _) <- name]
```

This means "Get a tuple whose first element we will call `name`, from a list called `name`, and put those elements `name` in a list." Can you spot the mistake? You're giving the same name to the element and to the list, so of course it won't compile. And you're not binding any symbol to the input list (on the left hand side of the `=`).

```
nameList names = [name | (name, _) <- names]
--       ^--takes a list called names  ^
--                                     |
--       And puts it into the list comprehension
```

Unless there is a requirement for you to implement `nameList` as a list comprehension, it can also be implemented using the `Functor` instance of a list:

```
nameList = fmap fst
```